# Повторение html блока при обработке JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Получаю данные о пользователях в **JSON**.

Задача обработать и выводить данные каждого пользователя в отдельном `html` блоке по порядку.

В данный момент вывод данных реализован примерным образом

```
$('.text').append('<div class='user_name'><span>' + user.name+ '</span><div>');
```

Т.к.  подобным способом нужно будет вставлять приличное количество тегов `html`,  решение не самое удачное.

Если ли способ написания шаблона `html` блока и при каждом новом пользователе 
вставлять его и заполнять нужными данными?

Comment: Для создания html можно использовать объектный подход, вида: `$('div',{class:'user_name',append:$('<span>',{html:user.name})});`

Answer (score -1):

Как самый тривиальный вариант:

```
function generateUserHtmlBlock(user) {
  return "<div class='user_name'><span>" + user.name + "</span><div>";
}

$.ajax({
  ...,
  success: function(users) {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      $('.text').append(generateUserHtmlBlock(users[i]));
    }
  }
})
```

Советую посмотреть в сторону компонентного подхода.

Comment: Чем ваш способ отличается от способа автора, не понятно. Автор имеет ввиду, что метод `append` без конца будет добавлять блоки, без какой либо проверки на существование и как я понял, ему так-же не устраивает сам подход для создания `html` блока.